# How to keep trailing space from source to destination using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl

##### Environment

- **Source**: Oracle database via OLE DB
- **Destination**: SQL Server 2019 via OLE DB
- **Tools**: SSIS Visual Studio 2019

##### Problem

The source has value with space (e.g. `12345` ) but loaded into target database space is gone (e.g. `12345`)

I want to keep all spaces in source data and input the same into the target table but cannot find the configuration or any way to keep those spaces.

Comment: Do the source and destination table columns have the same data types? I think you should provide more information about the source and destination columns. Besides, is any transformation applied to the source column before loading it into SQL Server?

Comment: Besides, I suggest adding a data viewer into your data pipeline to check if the OLE DB source removes the trailing spaces or the OLE DB Destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is data type on target table.
Oracle uses VARCHAR2 and CHAR datatypes, and SSIS define them to Unicode string.

The first time, I declared a column for character with VARCHAR in SQL Server but found extra space missing after ETL.
I have changed data type in SQL Server from VARCHAR to NVARCHAR, that can resolve my problem.

Comment: You should mark this answer as accepted even if it is your answer.